# How do I find out why a mongo mapper model save takes so long?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongomapper

What are ways to profile or dig into a mongo mapper model to see why it takes so long to save?

I'm using it in Sinatra if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Ruby profiler, for example the ruby-prof gem (http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/). This will show you which method slows down your code.